# How to create a link in React component with onClick handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

What is proper / standard way how to create link with onClick callback function without `URL`?

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>click me!</a>
```

or without `href`, but then a link is not visually clickable:

```
<a onClick={this.handleClick}>click me!</a>
```

All tutorials, I have read, work with another element than `<a>` - clickable `<span>`, `<div>` etc. but I would like to use `<a>`.

Comment: Depends where you want the link to go. If it's for internal app navigation, then the routing library will likely have a `<Link>` component that will do this for you, otherwise you will have to just use css to style it like a link. But again I  would suggest making an independent component to do this.

Answer (score 9):

You may set `cursor: pointer;` for a link to achieve behavior of real url link :)

```
<a onClick={this.handleClick} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

`href="javascript:void(0)"` is better than `href="#"`.

`href="#"` will cause the url changed.

Comment: `href="javascript:void(0)"` will evoke a warning if you use linting: `warning  Script URL is a form of eval  no-script-url`

Answer (score 2):

For anchor tag in REACT, if we want to use onClick without URL change, then can use the following

```
<a
    style={{ cursor:"pointer" }}
    href={null}
    onClick={() =>
                  this.toggleModal("Rental Objects With Current Rent")
                }
 >
Click Me
</a>
```

OR

```
<a
        style={{ cursor:"pointer" }}
        href={void (0)}
        onClick={() =>
                      this.toggleModal("Rental Objects With Current Rent")
                    }
     >
    Click Me
    </a>
```

**Note**: Instead of cursor:pointer we can also use in CSS file

```
a:not([href]):not([tabindex]){
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #0086ce;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '../../components/CustomButtons/Button';

 onRegister = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/signupAsTeacher');
  };
<Button onClick={this.onRegister}> Contact Us </Button>

export default withRouter(functionName);
```

You must first import withRouter. Then you should give the page path to the button click event. The last one is the export withRouter.

Answer (score 0):

Eslint says to use a button:

> [eslint] Anchor used as a button. Anchors are primarily expected to navigate. Use the button element instead. [Error]

```
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={this.onBtnClick.bind(this, key)}
>
    {link[key]}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the easiest way:

```
<a href="/" onClick={this.handleClick}></a>
```